# JQuery Tabs - issue with nested tabs - Activating sub tab on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have an issue with nested jquery tabs and needs some help/pointer.

Currently I have 5 Parent tabs and have few sub tabs under each parent tabs.

When page gets loaded I want to show a particular Parent tab and one of its child tab active.

I am able to activate a particular parent tab but same is not working with child tabs.

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue and has any solution to share.

Reference - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Thanks & Regards,
Ajay

Comment: WOuld help if you could provide a demo of your problem. Try http://www.jsbin.com.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tabs being loaded with ajax content? If so you will have to set the child active tab in the load callback....example [in this thread.](http://www.nabble.com/Selecting-nested-tabs-with-text-link-td20109146s27240.html)
If you not doing this please provide your script and I will assist you.